# SharePoint Provider Hosted Apps - Hosting the .net Code

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, visual-studio, provider-hosted-app, office

Architecture type question...

We are using Office 365 and building numerous event receivers, provider hosted apps etc

Currently, each provider hosted app we build has an associated web site where the .net code is deployed to - using Azure web site for this.

As I understand, it's not supported / (possible?) for many provider hosted apps to share the same Azure site as the backend - because of the 1-1 relationship between the app and the azure site.

We are finding ourselves creating a lot of azure sites, which is ok but over time will become unmanageable - and will start to cost a fair amount of money.

I'm keen to know how other developers are overcoming this? if there are any solutions?

Would it be possible to create a VM within Azure, and host many websites within IIS (one site per app), or even 1 virtual directory per app. Would this be a supported scenario with Office 365?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your app can be hosted absolutely anywhere, just that Azure simplifies the process.

Setting it up is a pretty mean feat though, complete information of setting up IIS for doing this is thin on the ground, as you need to fully configure DNS, and purchase wildcard certificates (the backend comms is HTTPS only) Google around for "On Premises SharePoint Hosted Apps" or there abouts.

Here's an example article that covers much of what you need to do: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/01/31/configuring-sharepoint-on-premise-deployments-for-apps.aspx